# How do I hide NavBar of my website when using in mobile with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm building an website with reactjs and I want to achieve something like Instagram. So when a user access this website in pc they should be seeing navbar and if the user access it on Thier phone then they should be seeing bottom tab navigation and navbar should be hidden. I'm also attaching my design photo's of both desktop and mobile UI so you guys can have better idea. Also I'm not using any UI library just plain simple reactjs.[image: Mobile UI]

[image: desktop UI]

Comment: Create two versions of navbars, one for desktop, and another for mobile.
Use media queries, to hide as per screensize.

Comment: @AshishJhanwar should I create seperate navbar component for both and import them in my app.js? If so then where should I use media queries?

Comment: Yup. 

Create a single base component which has all the controlling functions (changing to a different tab on icon click for example), extend your two purely ui components from the base components.

Comment: @AshishJhanwar and media queries? At what file should I use it? App.js or app.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing any other way, I would recommend you to use a media query of CSS. It will make your life easy.
You just have to instruct what part of code you want to hide.
Suppose the class of your navbar is  then just put as below in media query and put CDN of bootstrap to your page.
i.e.

```
 @media query("Size for what you want to hide navbar)(i.e. 480px or 320px)
          .nav {
               visibility; hidden;
           }
```

Comment: That's great! Can I also use pure Bootstrap just for responsiveness? I don't need jQuery because menu like drop can be designed in react itself.

Comment: Yes. You can use pure bootstrap and CSS combination to achieve responsiveness. Not only for Desktop, Mobile even you can achieve for tablets and iPads too.
And coming to your second point of jQuery problem. It can also be solved with bootstrap itself. It'll make your coding less and easily readable. As you just have to mention inbuilt functions.

Comment: thanks! Is there any tutorials available for same or some docs for the installation of bootstrap information. In a plain HTML website we just download bootstrap file and import it in html. But don't have any idea how do I implement in react?

Comment: You just have the below-mentioned line of codes into your HTML head nothing else. If you are connected to the internet. Else you can refer bootstrap's official website.

Comment: Actually due to comment character limitations I can't put them here. But mentioning the website from where just copy the lines of CDN and put it into your <head></head> and you are done.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solutions to this would be to have two versions of navbars.

a Nav, and a NavMobile.

You can use css media queries to hide/show them as per min/max screen size, this is one of the most common practices

Comment: Okay so I should create 2 seperate navbar components for both larger screen and small screen and import them in my app.js? If so then where should I use media queries?

Comment: In the desktop one, use media queries to hide the nav if screen-size is smaller than a specific width (maxwidth: 720px) for example  
and in the mobile one, hide when screen is larger than a specific width (minwidth: 719px) for example.

Comment: The media queries should be in the css files of your component, instead of a global css file, encapsulation is important to prevent conflicts.